# Constructor returning only this

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've a class that needs to return a function value inside when initiated. The code looks something like this.

```
class MyClass {
  get list() {
    return [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
  }

  // CANNOT BE CHANGED
  constructor() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to invoke and return what I've in my `list()` when running `new MyClass()` without changing the constructor?

EDIT: So the code below should be as follows
`x = new BrandCollector();`
then `x` should equal `[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: So are you saying you want it so that if you do `let x = new MyClass()` you'd expect `x` to be `[1,2,4,5,6]`? If so... why?

Comment: What are you expecting the end result to be when you call `new MyClass()`? Should the caller receive the `list` array? I'm not sure how to parse "needs to return a function value inside when initiated" or "invoke and return what I've in my `list()`".

Comment: What can be changed? Can we change `list`? Can we add new properties to `MyClass`?

Comment: `console.log( (new MyClass).list )`?

Comment: yes, I can change list and MyClass in general, without the constructor.  When I do `let x = new MyClass()`, x should be [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: Sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346503/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-xy-problem). Why would you want to call a *constructor* with `new` and expect something that's not an instance of the class?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. When you call `new Foo()` you must get a `Foo` back. That's what `new` does; returning anything else would break everything. (And it's a non-sensical constructor. You *can*, but it completely breaks expectations.)

Comment: @JamesThorpe it's an university assignment that I've spent over an hour to try and solve.

Comment: Are you sure you've understood the requirement - are you able to expand on it in the Q?  It sounds a bit of an odd assignment - you certainly wouldn't expect a constructor to give you anything but an instance of a class.

Comment: @trincot that's not allowed unfortunately

Comment: @JamesThorpe yep, it's in front of me.

Comment: What *is* allowed? Changing `list` method? Extending the class? ...

Comment: @trincot yep, that should be allowed. Everything in the class can be modified without the constructor.

Comment: @Lexx Speaking as a CS graduate, I'm having trouble imagining an assignment that would have you do something so bizarre. Could you include the assignment's problem statement in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redefine the class as a proxy of itself:

```js
class MyClass {
  get list() {
    return [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
  }

  // CANNOT BE CHANGED
  constructor() {
    return this;
  }
}

MyClass = new Proxy(MyClass, { construct: () => MyClass.prototype.list });

let x = new MyClass;
console.log(x);
```

Comment: That's a very clean solution, thank you! I'm not sure if it passes, but I'm gonna try.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a new class to the old one.

```js
class MyClass {
    get list() {
        return [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
    }      

    // CANNOT BE CHANGED
    constructor() {
    }
}

class MyClass1 {
    get list() {
        return [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
    }      

    constructor() {
        return this.list;
    }
}

MyClass = MyClass1;
var x = new MyClass;
console.log(x);
```

Comment: That's a good solution, not sure if it can be accepted as the task implies I should be modifying the main class, but hey.

Comment: do you think that a class constructor can be overridden with a prototype function?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is not possible, but there are other ways to approach that.

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(values){
   this.myArray = values
  }

  static List(){
    return [1,2,3,4] // option 1
    return new this([1,2,3,4]) //option 2
  }
}
```

usage

```
const a = MyClass.List()
```

in case of option1 will return the simple Array, in option2 will return the class with your Array as attribute `a.myArray`

Does that help you?

Comment: I can't do it like that.